# JavaScript innerHTML will only work at end of loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I'm trying to make a dice roller using JavaScript, and want the dice to cycle through a few values, and visually show these, before stopping on a final number.

I'm however having trouble with getting `innerHTML` to work as intended.

The code I'm running

```
function test() {
    var testArray = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        container.innerHTML = testArray[i];
        sleep(50);
    }
}
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I run the `test()` function it wont visually cycle through the array and only shows the last number of the array on the HTML page.

I have tried to use the `setTimeout` function, and gotten the same results, I have also tried setting the delay time higher.

Comment: Using a `sleep()` type method in Javascript is a bad idea because it blocks execution, which is why you're not seeing the page update until the whole process is complete.  Also, that loop is weird.  If you wanted a synchronous sleep method (which you shouldn't!) just use a while loop.  But don't.

Comment: @Archer using console.log results the expected behavior, why is it odd with innerHTML?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal that is excactly what I was wondering about, I know this is bad practice, I was just wondering why it seemed to work in different ways.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal The page isn't refreshed because of the code blocking execution which stops it rendering.  The console must simply be a different thread - I've never tried that because I don't write blocking code (and never would).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `setInterval` in order to give the browser a chance to update the window.

The problem here is that JavaScript is single-threaded. And for most browsers, this thread is also used to update the UI. Because of that, your window will not be updated until the script is completely finished.

Using `setInterval` pushes the function onto the queue to be executed at a later point after the running script has finished and the UI had time to update.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');

test();

function test() {
    var testArray = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (i >= testArray.length - 1) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    
        container.innerHTML = testArray[i];
        
        i++;
    }, 50);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```